# How to input text in input field automatically with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to input text in an INPUT field automatically with Selenium. The tricky part is that the INPUT tag is generated only when I click on the field.

Below is the HTML that is generated after I click on the field:

```
<span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 698.2px; left: 143.788px;">
  <span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 310px; margin-top: -47px;">
    <span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown">
      <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox">
      <em class="vivacom-icon icon-arrow_up input-with-select-arrow-up"></em>
    </span>
    <span class="select2-results">
      <ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
        <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-result-exw5-876002661" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 876 002661</li>
        <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-result-0a0v-877749591" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 877 749591</li>
        <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-result-abu9-876682597" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 876 682597</li>
        <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-result-qim0-879314424" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 879 314424</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Also, this is INPUT with a dropdown, so I can choose something from the dropdown result or type in the input field. The problem is that none of the two I managed to do.

This below is the code to expand the dropdown menu:

```
drop_down_menu_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="sendSmsMessageForm"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]')
drop_down_menu_button.click()
```

After executing, the dropdown is expanded, but I didn't succeed to click something from the result or to type something in the field (automatically).

[This is the dropdown result after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAXiq.png)

[And this is the HTML that is generated after clicking. I think that the upper script is reliable for the creating of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y3U5.png)

I tried different things such as:

At all none of the below works!

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
driver.execute_script('(function(){try{"gtm_isp_lookup",!0,"","/"}catch(a){}var c="https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/?key\x3dgJkinLrBaaaGv26vSxA5",b=new XMLHttpRequest;b.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4==this.readyState&&200==this.status){var a=JSON.parse(this.responseText);if("success"===a.status)try{window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],window.dataLayer.push({event:"isp-lookup","isp-lookup":{lat:a.lat,lon:a.lon,isp:a.isp,org:a.org,continent:a.continent,country:a.country,region:a.region,city:a.city,businessName:a.businessName, businessWebsite:a.businessWebsite}})}catch(d){}}};b.open("GET",c,!0);b.send()})();')
time.sleep(10)
input_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input')))
```

The goal of this below is to click on the first number, but the problem is that the XPath of the number is changing on each refresh, and it is impossible to work this way.

```
first_number = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-result-od25-876002661"]')
first_number.click()
```

This below is also not working:

```
number_input = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input')
number_input.send_keys("876002661")
```

This below is also not working:

```
partial_text = "876002661"
options = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="select2-senderMsisdnSelect-results"]/li')
for option in options:
    if partial_text in option.text:
        option.click()
        break
```

You are my last hope...

Comment: Can you share a link to the page? I get what you are describing but it will be MUCH easier to figure out a solution if I can see the page for myself.